# opening a file and writing into a new file in a for loop

Tags: python

I am trying to make a new text file by writing data into it under a for loop. It sort of works but it does not write all the data I require within the file. Can someone please help?

here is the code:

```
    def process_images(base_file, output_dir, labels_path, l_out, sample_size):

      base_file = base_file 
      output_dir = output_dir

      if not os.path.exists(output_dir):

         os.makedirs(output_dir)
         list_ims = sorted(os.listdir(base_file))

         for counter, img in enumerate(list_ims):
             if counter > sample_size:
                 print('Reached the end of the sample size')
                 break
             else:
                 print('processing image number {} with name {}'.format(counter, img))
                 im = cv.imread(os.path.join(base_file, img))
                 output_path = os.path.join(output_dir, img)
                 result = face_detector(counter, im, output_path)

                 if result:

                   with open(labels_path, 'r') as d:
                     with open(l_out, 'w+') as f:
                       lines = d.readlines()[1:]
                       for line in lines:
                          file_name = line.split('/')[0].split()[1]
                          if file_name == img:
                             f.write(line)
                          else:
                             continue
```

The face detector is another function and outputs true if there is a face in the image. If result is true, then the function should load a file and search for the img name in the file. If that happens, it should write this file name in another text file.

The issue I am having is, it does so only for the first iteration in the loop, not the others. I do not get any error, its only that the other image names are not being written in the new text file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the file with `‘a’` option.

```
with open(l_out, 'a') as f:
```